# Spring Boot not able to detect the values that I have key in

Tags: java, spring, angular, mongodb, spring-boot

I have problem regarding inserting data from angular to spring boot by rest API using mongodb atlas as the database. I have create another variable called numbers to test it out. But it turns out that the values was able to capture on angular but not in spring boot. Below are my codes:

Angular code:

```
<div class="todo-content">
<h1 class="page-title">My Todos</h1>
<div class="todo-create">
  <form #todoForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit) = "createTodo(todoForm)" novalidate>
    <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Type a todo and press enter..." 
           required
           name="title" [(ngModel)]="newTodo.title"
           #title="ngModel" >     

    <input type="text" id="numbers" class="form-control" placeholder="Type a todo and press enter..." 
           required
           name="numbers" [(ngModel)]="newTodo.numbers"
           #numbers="ngModel" >     

    <div *ngIf="title.errors && title.dirty"
         class="alert alert-danger">
        <div [hidden]="!title.errors.required">
          Title is required.
        </div>
    </div>

    <td><button class="btn btn-danger" (ngSubmit) = "createTodo(todoForm)"> submit User</button></td>
  </form>
</div>
<ul class="todo-list">
  <li *ngFor="let todo of todos" [class.completed]= "todo.completed === true" >
    <div class="todo-row" *ngIf="!editing || editingTodo.id != todo.id">
        <a class="todo-completed" (click)="toggleCompleted(todo)">
          <i class="material-icons toggle-completed-checkbox"></i> 
        </a> 
        <span class="todo-title">
          {{todo.title}}
        </span>
        <span class="todo-actions">
            <a (click)="editTodo(todo)">
              <i class="material-icons edit">edit</i>
            </a>
            <a (click)="deleteTodo(todo.id)">
              <i class="material-icons delete">clear</i>
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="todo-edit" *ngIf="editing && editingTodo.id === todo.id">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" 
         [(ngModel)]="editingTodo.title" required>
        <span class="edit-actions">
            <a (click)="updateTodo(editingTodo)">
              <i class="material-icons">done</i>
            </a>
            <a (click)="clearEditing()">
              <i class="material-icons">clear</i>
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="no-todos" *ngIf="todos && todos.length == 0">
    <p>No Todos Found!</p>
</div>
```

todo-list.component.ts

```
  import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TodoService } from './todo.service';
import { Todo } from './todo';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'todo-list',
  templateUrl: './todo-list.component.html'
})

export class TodoListComponent implements OnInit {
  todos: Todo[];
  newTodo: Todo = new Todo();
  editing: boolean = false;
  editingTodo: Todo = new Todo();

  constructor(
    private todoService: TodoService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getTodos();
  }

  getTodos(): void {
    this.todoService.getTodos()
      .then(todos => this.todos = todos );    
  }

  createTodo(todoForm: NgForm): void {
    console.log(this.newTodo.numbers);
    console.log(todoForm);
    this.todoService.createTodo(this.newTodo)
      .then(createTodo => {    
        todoForm.reset();
        this.newTodo = new Todo();
        this.todos.unshift(createTodo)
      });
  }

  deleteTodo(id: string): void {
    this.todoService.deleteTodo(id)
    .then(() => {
      this.todos = this.todos.filter(todo => todo.id != id);
    });
  }

  updateTodo(todoData: Todo): void {
    console.log(todoData);
    this.todoService.updateTodo(todoData)
    .then(updatedTodo => {
      let existingTodo = this.todos.find(todo => todo.id === updatedTodo.id);
      Object.assign(existingTodo, updatedTodo);
      this.clearEditing();
    });
  }

  toggleCompleted(todoData: Todo): void {
    todoData.completed = !todoData.completed;
    this.todoService.updateTodo(todoData)
    .then(updatedTodo => {
      let existingTodo = this.todos.find(todo => todo.id === updatedTodo.id);
      Object.assign(existingTodo, updatedTodo);
    });
  }

  editTodo(todoData: Todo): void {
    this.editing = true;
    Object.assign(this.editingTodo, todoData);
  }

  clearEditing(): void {
    this.editingTodo = new Todo();
    this.editing = false;
  }
}
```

todo.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Todo } from './todo';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class TodoService {
  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getTodos():  Promise<Todo[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/api/todos/')
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json() as Todo[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  createTodo(todoData: Todo): Promise<Todo> {
    console.log("inside service");
    console.log(todoData);
    console.log(todoData.numbers);
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/api/todos/', todoData, "a")
      .toPromise().then(response => response.json() as Todo)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  updateTodo(todoData: Todo): Promise<Todo> {
    return this.http.put(this.baseUrl + '/api/todos/' + todoData.id, todoData)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json() as Todo)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  deleteTodo(id: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.delete(this.baseUrl + '/api/todos/' + id)
      .toPromise()
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('Some error occured', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

todo.ts

```
export class Todo {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  numbers: string;
  completed: boolean;
  createdAt: Date;
}
```

Spring Boot:

TodoController

```
package com.example.todoapp.controllers;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import com.example.todoapp.models.Todo;
import com.example.todoapp.repositories.TodoRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class TodoController {

    @Autowired
    TodoRepository todoRepository;

    @GetMapping("/todos")
    public List<Todo> getAllTodos() {
        Sort sortByCreatedAtDesc = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "createdAt");
        return todoRepository.findAll(sortByCreatedAtDesc);
    }

    @PostMapping("/todos")
    public Todo createTodo(@Valid @RequestBody Todo todo, String numbers) {
        System.out.println(todo.getNumber());
        System.out.println(todo.getTitle());
        System.out.println(numbers+ "numbers");
        todo.setCompleted(false);
        return todoRepository.save(todo);
    }

    @PostMapping("/contact")
    public Todo createContact(@Valid @RequestBody Todo todo) {
        todo.setCompleted(false);
        return todoRepository.save(todo);
    }

    @GetMapping(value="/todos/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Todo> getTodoById(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        return todoRepository.findById(id)
                .map(todo -> ResponseEntity.ok().body(todo))
                .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }

    @PutMapping(value="/todos/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Todo> updateTodo(@PathVariable("id") String id,
                                           @Valid @RequestBody Todo todo) {
        return todoRepository.findById(id)
                .map(todoData -> {
                    todoData.setTitle(todo.getTitle());
                    todoData.setCompleted(todo.getCompleted());
                    Todo updatedTodo = todoRepository.save(todoData);
                    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(updatedTodo);
                }).orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value="/todos/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteTodo(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        return todoRepository.findById(id)
                .map(todo -> {
                    todoRepository.deleteById(id);
                    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
                }).orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }
}
```

TodoRepository

```
package com.example.todoapp.repositories;

import com.example.todoapp.models.Todo;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface TodoRepository extends MongoRepository<Todo, String> {

}
```

Todo

```
package com.example.todoapp.models;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection="todos")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt"}, allowGetters = true)
public class Todo {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max=100)
    @Indexed(unique=true)
    private String title;

    @Size(max=100)
    @Indexed(unique=false)
    private String numbers;

    private Boolean completed = false;

    private Date createdAt = new Date();

    public Todo() {
        super();
    }

    public Todo(String title, String numbers) {
        this.title = title;
        this.numbers= numbers;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Boolean getCompleted() {
        return completed;
    }

    public void setCompleted(Boolean completed) {
        this.completed = completed;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }



    public String getNumber() {
        return numbers;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.numbers = number;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Todo[id=%s, title='%s',numbers='%s', completed='%s']",
                id, title,numbers, completed);
    }
}
```

Error from angular:

```
fff
todo-list.component.ts:32 NgForm {_submitted: true, ngSubmit: EventEmitter, form: FormGroup}
todo.service.ts:20 inside service
todo.service.ts:21 Todo {a: true, title: "My Web Application went blank on private mode", numbers: "fff"}
todo.service.ts:22 fff
```

Error From spring boot:

```
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.0.RELEASE)

2018-11-10 16:13:21.940  INFO 9436 --- [           main] com.example.todoapp.TodoappApplication   : Starting TodoappApplication on NCS-180417AV05 with PID 9436 (E:\Project\portfolio_website\templates\spring-boot-mongodb-angular-todo-app-master\spring-boot-backendv2\target\classes started by royyzh in E:\Project\portfolio_website\templates\spring-boot-mongodb-angular-todo-app-master\spring-boot-backendv2)
2018-11-10 16:13:21.944  INFO 9436 --- [           main] com.example.todoapp.TodoappApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-11-10 16:13:21.992  INFO 9436 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@327b636c: startup date [Sat Nov 10 16:13:21 SGT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-11-10 16:13:23.367  INFO 9436 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-11-10 16:13:23.393  INFO 9436 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-11-10 16:13:23.393  INFO 9436 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.28
2018-11-10 16:13:23.399  INFO 9436 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin;C:\curl;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;D:\eclipes java ee\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-4.0.3\bin;C:\Users\royyzh\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\royyzh\AppData\Local\Programs\EmEditor;D:\sts-bundle\sts-3.9.5.RELEASE;;.]
2018-11-10 16:13:23.692  INFO 9436 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-11-10 16:13:23.693  INFO 9436 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1705 ms
2018-11-10 16:13:23.792  INFO 9436 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-11-10 16:13:23.797  INFO 9436 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-11-10 16:13:23.798  INFO 9436 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-11-10 16:13:23.798  INFO 9436 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-11-10 16:13:23.798  INFO 9436 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-11-10 16:13:24.698  INFO 9436 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-00-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-01-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-02-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=REPLICA_SET, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500, requiredReplicaSetName='RoyYipProjectCluster-shard-0'}
2018-11-10 16:13:24.698  INFO 9436 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-00-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
2018-11-10 16:13:24.746  INFO 9436 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-01-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
2018-11-10 16:13:24.747  INFO 9436 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-02-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 to client view of cluster
2018-11-10 16:13:25.123  INFO 9436 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : No server chosen by com.mongodb.Mongo$4@2e52fb3e from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-01-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, ServerDescription{address=royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-00-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, ServerDescription{address=royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-02-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
2018-11-10 16:13:25.138  INFO 9436 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:4829}] to royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-02-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017
2018-11-10 16:13:25.149  INFO 9436 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-02-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 0, 4]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=7, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=9102165, setName='RoyYipProjectCluster-shard-0', canonicalAddress=royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-02-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, hosts=[royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-00-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-01-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-02-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-00-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=1, lastWriteDate=Sat Nov 10 16:13:26 SGT 2018, lastUpdateTimeNanos=33621241304334}
2018-11-10 16:13:25.158  INFO 9436 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : No server chosen by WritableServerSelector from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-01-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, ServerDescription{address=royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-00-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, ServerDescription{address=royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-02-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 0, 4]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=7, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=9102165, setName='RoyYipProjectCluster-shard-0', canonicalAddress=royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-02-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, hosts=[royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-00-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-01-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-02-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-00-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=1, lastWriteDate=Sat Nov 10 16:13:26 SGT 2018, lastUpdateTimeNanos=33621241304334}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
2018-11-10 16:13:25.201  INFO 9436 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:4482}] to royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-01-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017
2018-11-10 16:13:25.204  INFO 9436 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:4726}] to royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-00-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017
2018-11-10 16:13:25.209  INFO 9436 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-01-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_SECONDARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 0, 4]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=7, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=7415729, setName='RoyYipProjectCluster-shard-0', canonicalAddress=royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-01-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, hosts=[royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-00-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-01-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-02-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-00-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=1, lastWriteDate=Sat Nov 10 16:13:26 SGT 2018, lastUpdateTimeNanos=33621301859146}
2018-11-10 16:13:25.210  INFO 9436 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-00-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 0, 4]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=7, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=5801588, setName='RoyYipProjectCluster-shard-0', canonicalAddress=royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-00-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, hosts=[royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-00-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-01-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-02-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-00-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=7fffffff0000000000000005, setVersion=1, lastWriteDate=Sat Nov 10 16:13:26 SGT 2018, lastUpdateTimeNanos=33621302845567}
2018-11-10 16:13:25.210  INFO 9436 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Setting max election id to 7fffffff0000000000000005 from replica set primary royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-00-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017
2018-11-10 16:13:25.210  INFO 9436 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Setting max set version to 1 from replica set primary royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-00-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017
2018-11-10 16:13:25.210  INFO 9436 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Discovered replica set primary royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-00-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017
2018-11-10 16:13:25.296  INFO 9436 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:4726}] to royyipprojectcluster-shard-00-00-uwgni.gcp.mongodb.net:27017
2018-11-10 16:13:25.698  INFO 9436 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@327b636c: startup date [Sat Nov 10 16:13:21 SGT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-11-10 16:13:25.763  INFO 9436 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/contact],methods=[POST]}" onto public com.example.todoapp.models.Todo com.example.todoapp.controllers.TodoController.createContact(com.example.todoapp.models.Todo)
2018-11-10 16:13:25.765  INFO 9436 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/todos/{id}],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.example.todoapp.models.Todo> com.example.todoapp.controllers.TodoController.getTodoById(java.lang.String)
2018-11-10 16:13:25.766  INFO 9436 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/todos],methods=[POST]}" onto public com.example.todoapp.models.Todo com.example.todoapp.controllers.TodoController.createTodo(com.example.todoapp.models.Todo,java.lang.String)
2018-11-10 16:13:25.767  INFO 9436 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/todos],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.example.todoapp.models.Todo> com.example.todoapp.controllers.TodoController.getAllTodos()
2018-11-10 16:13:25.767  INFO 9436 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/todos/{id}],methods=[PUT]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.example.todoapp.models.Todo> com.example.todoapp.controllers.TodoController.updateTodo(java.lang.String,com.example.todoapp.models.Todo)
2018-11-10 16:13:25.768  INFO 9436 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/api/todos/{id}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.example.todoapp.controllers.TodoController.deleteTodo(java.lang.String)
2018-11-10 16:13:25.771  INFO 9436 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-11-10 16:13:25.771  INFO 9436 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-11-10 16:13:25.793  INFO 9436 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-11-10 16:13:25.793  INFO 9436 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-11-10 16:13:25.840  INFO 9436 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-11-10 16:13:25.995  INFO 9436 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-11-10 16:13:26.060  INFO 9436 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-11-10 16:13:26.064  INFO 9436 --- [           main] com.example.todoapp.TodoappApplication   : Started TodoappApplication in 4.443 seconds (JVM running for 6.802)
2018-11-10 16:13:32.981  INFO 9436 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-11-10 16:13:32.981  INFO 9436 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-11-10 16:13:33.000  INFO 9436 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 18 ms
null
My Web Application went blank on private mode
nullnumbers
null
My Web Application went blank on private mode
nullnumbers
```

What should I do to make it work? Which part of my code needs to be changed and why?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few mistakes. Here are the fixes you need to make.

```
this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/api/todos/', todoData, "a")
```

What is the `"a"` doing in the `POST` call. You can remove that in `createTodo` method declared in `todo.service.ts`

In `Todo.java` the variable is declared as `numbers` and the `setter` is declared as

```
public void setNumber(String number) {
```

Change this to

```
 public void setNumbers(String numbers) {
    this.numbers = numbers;
 }
```

Now you can update `createTodo` method in `TodoController.java` to the following

```
@PostMapping("/todos")
public Todo createTodo(@Valid @RequestBody Todo todo) {
```